# How can split lines inside a list?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and for a homework assignment I need to read a CSV file using openfiledialog then adding them to a list but I can't figure out how I can split the lines using a ','.

I have already tried to add .split after lines and I already tried adding value also but it doesn't allow it.

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
var fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    List<Employee_Record> Employees = new List<Employee_Record>();
    var lines = sr.ReadLine();
    var value = lines.Split(',');

    Employees.Add(new Employee_Record() { Name = lines, Address = lines, Age = lines, GrossMonthlyPay = lines, DepartmentID = lines, DeveloperType = lines, TaxType = lines });
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Employees;
}
```

Comment: Use a dedicated CSV parser and make your life easier with less headaches

Comment: Have you stepped through your code, what line is the problem?

Comment: What if the address has a comma in it? its gunna go booom

Answer (score 2):

You have to access the value array. Not the lines. And you need a loop to read line by line.

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    List<Employee_Record> Employees = new List<Employee_Record>();

    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)  
    {  
        var value = line.Split(','); 

        //// some positions can be empty. So handle that
        Employees.Add(new Employee_Record() 
          {   
              Name = value[0] , 
              Address = value[1] , 
              Age = value[2] , 
              GrossMonthlyPay = value[3] , 
              DepartmentID = value[4] , 
              DeveloperType = value[5] , 
              TaxType = value[6]  
          });
    }  

    dataGridView1.DataSource = Employees;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, worked perfectly without any errors Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a CSV like this one:

```
2A,18,Stephen Hawk,math,96
```

I would simply use regEx with C# to parse it.

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
var fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;

using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    List<Employee_Record> Employees = new List<Employee_Record>();
    var lines = sr.ReadLine();
    Regex re = new Regex(@"\W?");
    MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(lines);
    int mIdx=0;
    foreach (Match m in mc){
        Console.writeline(m.Value);
    }
// Do your logic here as you wish
}
```

//Expected output
2A
18
Stephen Hawk
math
96